# Get reference to the current instance of Shell window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am trying to show Modal Dialog and I need reference to the current Shell window:

```
public class OpenPopupWindowAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        var popup = new ChildWindow(); //(ChildWindow)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IPopupDialogWindow>();
        popup.Owner =  PlacementTarget ?? (Window)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IShell>();
```

I'm getting:

```
Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has not been shown previously.
```

This is the code from Bootstrapper

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        Container.RegisterInstance<IShell>(new Shell());
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

Interface:

```
public interface IShell
{
    void InitializeComponent();
}

public partial class Shell : Window, PrismDashboard.IShell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting up the container wrong.

This tells Unity to give you back the specific instance of `Shell` when an `IShell` is requested:

```
Container.RegisterInstance<IShell>(new Shell());
```

And this tells it to resolve an instance of `Shell` (not `IShell`) -- which it happily does, returning a different instance than before:

```
return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

As a result, when you later resolve an `IShell` from the container you get back a shell window that has not been used at all and its window handle has not been created.

Do this instead:

```
protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    var shell = new Shell();
    Container.RegisterInstance<IShell>(shell);
    return shell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. Do you have any other suggestions how this might be done in more appropriate way? I couldn't use Shell in Child window as project where Shell is already has reference to project where my Child window is. Workaround is IShell from Infrastructure project referenced from Child and Shell project.

Comment: @user927827: Totally depends on context. The arrangement with the Infrastructure project sounds reasonable.